# Changes made to httpd config file not taking effect

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, configuration, 64-bit

I am trying to configure apache on a 64-bit system running Windows 7. I installed apache using a win-32 installer (32-bit installer, which I guess is the reason behind problems). The installation was successful and I can browse to localhost in the browser.

**Problem**
But, I am not sure where to do the apache config changes. There is one `httpd-win` file inside `\Apache Group\Apache2\conf\` but no `httpd.conf` file. I did some changes inside the `httpd-win` file but the changes are not taking effect.

For example I tried to change the port number to fix one problem of apache not starting if skype is already running on my system. I changed the following line -

```
Listen @@Port@@
```

to

```
Listen 8080
```

But, still if skype is already running, apache does not start. Also, if I type some garbage in the file and restart apache, it works fine. I expected it to not run due to syntax errors.

Is it possible that all these problems are because I installed 32-bit apache on 64 -bit system. I also searched for 64-bit installer but did not find one yet. Can anybody tell me where to find one? Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: What version of Apache did you install? Apache 2.2.19 installs `httpd.conf` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf`. I could not find a `httpd-win`.

Comment: @gencha - version 2.0.55. The installer file's name is `apache_2.0.55-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi`

Comment: @gencha did you note that my system is 64-bit whereas I installed using a 32-bit installer?

Comment: @Sandeepan Yeah, I have the same situation on my system. Apache Server 2.0.55 is outdated and potentially insecure. The Apache website recommends 2.0.64 as the latest in the 2.0 branch. Do you require that version specifically?

Comment: No I dont specifically need that version. I am new in this team. All existing team members were using version 2.0.55 on a windows xp 32-bit system. The newer members are given a 64-bit system with windows 7. So, I am not sure how to go with the setup. We were considering Xampp installer but AFAIK, there are some cons of using XAMPP (if some more customizations are needed or what ...I don't exactly remember the cons.).  What do you suggest?

Comment: @Sandeepan, it sounds like your Apache is using a different httpd.conf file... As what you have referenced is clearly the unprocessed (has @@xxx@@ strings) file. As far as SkyPe goes, a reboot will usually cause Apache to get those ports 1st, and if not you can configure SkyPe to not use ports 80 and 443 with a couple of clicks. Also try a professional-grade WAMP package such as WampDeveloper Pro that will install everything for you and is meant for production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I was unable to reproduce this issue with Apache Server 2.0.55, as I only had 2.0.64 available. But to my understanding from what I have observed, httpd-win.conf is not intended as a configuration file. During the Apache Server installation (or when it starts for the first time) the file will be translated into httpd.conf.

Given that that did not seem to have happened in your case, either it is an issue with the 2.0.55 installer or with your installation.

I tried this on an x64 system as well (and with the x86 installer like you described). I don't assume that this is somehow responsible for your issue.

I would recommend reinstalling Apache Server and, if possible, use [2.0.64](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi). As that is the latest version in the 2.0 branch.